# Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object

Tags: windows, selenium, autoit

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/02/selenium-autoit-how-to-automate-non-browser-based-functionality/ to automate non-browser applications in Windows.

```
import java.io.File;
import autoitx4java.AutoItX;
import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;

import java.lang.System;

public class CalcTest {

    /**
     *
     * Returns if the JVM is 32 or 64 bit version
     */
    public static String jvmBitVersion(){
        return System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String jacobDllVersionToUse;
        if (jvmBitVersion().contains("32")){
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x86.dll";
        }
        else {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
        }

        File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
        System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

        AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
        x.run("calc.exe");
        x.winActivate("Calculator");
        x.winWaitActive("Calculator");
        //Enter 3
        x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "133") ;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Enter +
        x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "93") ;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Enter 3
        x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "133") ;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Enter =
        x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "121") ;
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
    at autoitx4java.AutoItX.<init>(AutoItX.java:181)
    at CalcTest.main(CalcTest.java:30)
```

The tutorial says that I should run `regsvr32 C:\install\AutoItX\AutoItX3_x64.dll` in cmd but I keep getting the following error:

```
The module "C:\install\AutoItX\AutoItX3_x64.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80070005
```

I'm not sure what to make of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to run cmd as an administrator. May as well leave this up. I'm sure someone might find themselves in the same boat one day...

Answer (score 4):

The following solution worked for me:

1. Copy `AutoItX3_x64.dll` file. You can find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoItX`.
2. Paste it in `C:\Windows\System32`.
3. Open a cmd prompt, run as administrator. Type `regsvr32 AutoItX3_x64.dll` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. You will get a message prompt as DllRegisterServer in AutoItX3_x64.dll succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

Run as Administrator login in cmd and since you are using 64 bit os ,run it in the path C:\Windows\SysWOW64

and for 32 bit run in path ,C:\Windows\System32

--Swapna Mhatre